# Why am I getting Nullpointer Exception when starting a Service(implements LocationListener) in android?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, forceclose, locationlistener

I am a newbie to Android. I have developed an app in which I am required to track a user's location using either gps, internet or using cellid.I am using 2 `Activities`(`MainActivity` and `SavelocationsActivity implements LocationListener`),a `Service(Ser)` and a `Broadcast Receiver(k)`.

When I click a `Button` in the `MainActivity` it was required to go to `SaveLocationsActivity`. I used to get that a few days before but now the `lattitude` and `longitude` values have become `null` and I am getting the following errors i.e:

```
null pointer exception.
```

As I am a newbie please explain me what to do and where I am going wrong step by step.Thank you in advance. I am posting the code and error log below.

SaveLocationsActivity

```
 public class SaveLocationsActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.savelocations);
   locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    //Toast.makeText(this,"in activity"+isNetworkEnabled ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          isGPSEnabled =       locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(isNetworkEnabled==true && isGPSEnabled==false)
    {
        getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    }
    else if(isGPSEnabled==true && isNetworkEnabled==false)
    {
        getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    else if(isGPSEnabled==true && isNetworkEnabled==true )
    {
        getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    private Location getLocation(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                6000, 10, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
              final String t5 = String.valueOf(latitude);
             final String t6 = String.valueOf(longitude);

            e5.setText(t5);
            e6.setText(t6);

            savelocation.put("t5",t5);
            savelocation.put("t6",t6);

            return location;
        }
    }
    return location;
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double latitude = l.getLatitude();
    double longitude = l.getLongitude();
    final String t5 = String.valueOf(latitude);
    final String t6 = String.valueOf(longitude);
    //Toast.makeText(SaveLocationsActivity.this,""+t5,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e5.setText(t5);
    e6.setText(t6);
}
```

Error logs:

```
  03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.broadcast/com.example.broadcast.SaveLocationsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at com.example.broadcast.SaveLocationsActivity.getLocation(SaveLocationsActivity.java:209)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at com.example.broadcast.SaveLocationsActivity.onCreate(SaveLocationsActivity.java:100)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
 03-21 23:34:50.309: E/AndroidRuntime(15368):   ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is line 209 in SaveLocationsActivity

Comment: this is line 209   double latitude = location.getLatitude();

Comment: double latitude = location.getLatitude();

Comment: You should look into Fused Location Provider, it makes GPS more efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method `getLocation()` the problem is probably here:

```
if (locationManager != null) {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

because `getLastKnownLocation` can return `null` if the previous location is unknown. So by calling `location.getLatitude()` you incur in a `NullPointerException`.
To avoid this you can check the returned value for `null` like:

```
if (locationManager != null) {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(location!=null)
         //...etc...
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for SavedLocations, but I got somewhat similar errors for the service Ser. Pls can You tell me what is going on? I tried to put the same code what you told for SavedLocationActivity but it didn't help. I am posting my log. pls do check it.

Comment: For Service Ser the problem could be the initialization of locationManager. Probably you call the method getLocation before the onStartCommand method has completed to initialize the service. This is legal because the Ser instance has been created by its constructor before. Try to put the initialization of locationManager in the constructor of the service.